# how to get key of item from list of dictionary when using generator expressions

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

I am trying to learn about generator expressions and how they work.

I have a list of dictionary like this,

```
la = [ {'app_name': 'MKV58YCF8RR','time_diff': 17647},
       {'app_name': 'ZXG68HYW4BA','time_diff': 18132}]
```

I wanted to get the maximum value of `time_diff` from it, which I did using `max`

```
max_val = max(value["time_diff"] for value in la)
```

This gives me,

```
18132
```

But I want to also print the `app_name` of this `time_diff`.

**Expected Output:**

```
ZXG68HYW4BA is 18132
```

**Current Output**

```
18132
```

Can someone please tell me how can I also get the `app_name` key as well?

**Edit:**

I think I need to use `map` but not sure how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `max` on `la` and provide a callable `key` such that you get the whole dictionary with the highest value for `time_diff`.

```
>>> la = [{'app_name': 'MKV58YCF8RR','time_diff': 17647},
...        {'app_name': 'ZXG68HYW4BA','time_diff': 18132}]
>>> 
>>> max_d = max(la, key=lambda d: d['time_diff']) # dict with max time_diff
>>> print('{d[app_name]} is {d[time_diff]}'.format(d=max_d))
ZXG68HYW4BA is 18132
```

> thank you, i don't understand how lambda is working here if there is no loop to iterate entire list.

Don't get distracted by the `lambda`. It is used as a criterion by which to select the maximum value of `la`, but we can write is as a normal function just as well.

```
>>> def criterion(dictionary):
...     return dictionary['time_diff']
... 
>>> max(la, key=criterion)
{'app_name': 'ZXG68HYW4BA', 'time_diff': 18132}
```

`max` iterates `la`, calls `criterion` with every element of `la`, and returns the element of `la` where `criterion` is maximal.

> can I extract it just like you did with lambda, while using itemgetter instead?

Sure!

```
>>> import operator
>>> max_d = max(la, key=operator.itemgetter('time_diff'))
>>> print('{d[app_name]} is {d[time_diff]}'.format(d=max_d))
ZXG68HYW4BA is 18132
```

Comment: thank you, i don't understand how lambda is working here if there is no loop to iterate entire list.

Comment: @MaverickD OK, I'll add an explanation.

Comment: thank you, can i do it using map instead? i mean while still using the `for` loop

Comment: @MaverickD well, you could shoehorn a `map` in there, but the current solution is the straight forward one.

Comment: @MaverickD also, about the `for` loop. `max` always iterates its first argument with a `for` loop internally. In your code, you give `max` a generator expression `(value["time_diff"] for value in la)`. In my code, I give `max` a list `la`. Both are iterable and `max` will iterate them internally.

Comment: thank you. i now understand why you are using `key`, i have used before `operator.itemgetter("time_diff")` for `key` but the problem is it prints entire item. I have used this before, `max(la, key=operator.itemgetter("time_diff"))` which prints `{'app_name': 'ZXG68HYW4BA', 'time_diff': 18132}`

Comment: @MaverickD your solution is correct, the itemgetter does the same as my lambda. All I added was to extract the key and the value in the `print`.

Comment: thank you. can i extract it just like you did with lambda, while using `itemgetter` instead?

Comment: @MaverickD sure, the `print` does not change, the itemgetter and the lambda do the same here.

Answer (score 2):

First determine the max value, like you did, then select the item that has this value:

```
max_time_diff = max(item["time_diff"] for item in la)
max_item = next(item for item in la if item["time_diff"] == max_time_diff)
```

`next()` picks the next item from an iterable.

In this particular case that iterable is exactly one item long, but in theory there could be more than one item that has a `time_diff` equal to `max_time_diff`, so `next()` makes sure that only the first matching item is picked.

Comment: but isn't it doing same thing twice?

Comment: Well, it iterates the input list twice(-ish), yes. On average it's not not exactly two times, because `next()` immediately stops the iteration as soon as it has an item, so the second list iteration is cut short. I would not worry about that too much, but it's not 100% optimal. Giving a `key` function to `max()` is better.